# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start method is opening default browser on Windows 11

Tags: c#, windows, system.diagnostics

I have a WinForms C# app that runs fine on Windows 10, but on Windows 11, the app is triggering the opening of a default browser window. I believe it is the Start() method of System.Diagnostics.Process that is causing the problem.  Here is my code.

```
Process ftpcopy = new Process();
ftpcopy.StartInfo.FileName = "ftpcopy.exe";
ftpcopy.StartInfo.Arguments = "ORGSHOWS " + _thisyear + " " + OrgID + " \"" + MainFolder + "\\\" \"" + TempFolder + "\"";
ftpcopy.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
ftpcopy.Start();
```

I'm trying to start ftpcopy.exe which is a program to do some folder creation and file copy work using FTP.

Any idea why the browser is getting started with this code?

Comment: probably on your win11, default application for that exe is browser?

Comment: Ah, interesting. Windows 11 might include a program named ftpcopy.exe.  If I do a Start, Run, ftpcopy.exe on Windows 10, nothing happens, but on Windows 11, a browser window opens up.  I'll try renaming my ftpcopy.exe program to another name.